# How do I get the NSOpenPanel Dialog to show the Media subsection

Tags: objective-c, openfiledialog, nsopenpanel

I would like to have the Media subsection in the sidebar of my Open File Dialog.It is visible in some Programs like Safari or Preview if you select File Open... and scroll down in the sidebar(It comes up underneath places, shared and search for)

I thought it might depend on the filetypes that I pass and already passed the array from CGImageSourceCopyTypeIdentifiers() to runModalforTypes cause I read that on cocoabuilder.com but no Media subsection. Any ideas how to make that appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. The problem were the following lines:

```
[oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:TRUE];

[oPanel setCanChooseFiles:FALSE];
```

that made the media section disappear.